# How to clear previous activity in a application use TabActivities which every tab is a activity

Tags: android

In scerenio, I have application calllog include 4 tabs ,first tab list all calls , the second list outgoing calls, the third is incoming calls, the fourth lists miss calls.Every tab is implement by activity.

when i enter my app , tab all calls is set first.After that there is a missed call on status bar.And i press icon missed calls,my app is implemented to launch tab missed call.At this time , I press Back button , it back tab all calls in my app.But I dont want to back tab all calls, i want to back activity before activity for tabs all calls.Do you have any way to do this?please help me , thanks a lot.

Comment: please refine your question to a more specific point. are you looking to prevent the back button terminate the TabActivity or looking for having more then one activity in a single tab.? these are two usual question asked and faced usually

Answer (score 0):

You should override a method from Activity like this.

```
@Override    
public void onPause() {    
    super.onPause();

    finish(); // Finishes the Activity.    
}
```